# How to open a PHP "/subPage" using the CLI? (For cron jobs)

Tags: php, rest, cron

I'm using a php server as a restful API endpoint for my app, and I need to set up a cronjob to regularly update the database.

The script runs when I visit a webpage as such:  "www.example.com/xmlAPI/public/xmlFetch"

However the cron job requires me to target a specific .php file. How can I achieve this? Do I need to use wget

Comment: Use `curl` or `wget` or other what you need.

Comment: If the api is written in a modular manner, you should be able to write a minimal cli script that calls the same methods. If its a big ball of mud then curl might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to pass a URL into a PHP file on the command line.

You can use argv in PHP though, which let's you specify arguments to the php and adds them to an array.

Here is a line of PHP which prints out $argv

```
<?php
var_dump($argv);
```

Here is the output:

```
Equinox -> php argvexample.php test this function
array(4) {
  [0]=>
   string(15) "argvexample.php"
  [1]=>
   string(4) "test"
  [2]=>
   string(4) "this"
  [3]=>
   string(8) "function"
}
```